# PHPMyAdmin throwing Error for INSERT ...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Tags: mysql, duplicates, key

On trying the following MySQL in PHPMyAdmin SQL Window, it is throwing error

```
INSERT INTO `stationlist`(`ID`, `Comd`, `Stn`, `Pin`, `Location`) 
        VALUES (Null, 'aaa','bb',11,'ddd') 
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE (Comd = 'abcd', Stn ='AFSB', Pin = 999, Location ='Delhi')
```

The error message is `"Unregcognised keyword"` for `ON DUPLICATE KEY` and all the succeeding tokens.

Is such Statement of `ON DUPLICATE KEY` not allowed in MySQL?

Comment: Any alternate method to achieve the same result? Can I use `Null` to for `Auto-increment` of `Primary Key` Column `ID`? Also, `ID` is the only Unique Index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the parentheses:

```
INSERT INTO `stationlist`(`ID`, `Comd_ID`, `Stn`, `Pin`, `Location`) 
VALUES (Null, 'aa','bb',11,'ddd') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `Comd_ID` = 'xxx', `Stn` ='AFSB', `Pin` = 999, `Location` ='Delhi'
```

Also it is recommended to omit the `auto-increment` column instead of passing `NULL` to it.

```
INSERT INTO `stationlist`(`Comd_ID`, `Stn`, `Pin`, `Location`) 
VALUES ('aa','bb',11,'ddd') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `Comd_ID` = 'xxx', `Stn` ='AFSB', `Pin` = 999, `Location` ='Delhi'
```

Notes:

- I don't know why you're setting `Comd_ID = 'xxx'`. If you need some help with setting the value appropriately, edit your question and explain what you want it to be.
- What values are you trying to avoid duplicating? The `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` clause is used with columns that have a unique index. Generally, you should avoid using an `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` clause on tables with multiple unique indexes.

Comment: I am using PHP Ver 5.6.19. It is NOT allowing SQL Pharse `ON DUPLICATE KEY`

Comment: Comd_ID is not an Index Value but String.

Comment: Your comments don't mean much. Of course `Comd_ID` is not an index value, it's the column name. It's just strange to set it to `xxx`, but it's not wrong if that's what you want. Which one of those 4 columns has a `UNIQUE` index?

Comment: I have already mentioned it the comment of original Post that  `ID` is the only Unique Index

Comment: Its alright, I have used alternate method in which I am using SQL INSERT to insert new records and SQL UPDATE to update existing records. Of course this is clumsy approach.

Comment: No, that's not a "clumsy approach". That's the right way to do it. If the ID is the only column with `UNIQUE` index, then `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` will be wasting an auto-incremented number every time. Not only that, but it's wasting resources by attempting to insert the row before deciding that it is a duplicate key and then trying to update. And in this case, your query is wrong and the only thing after the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` should be `ID=ID+1`.

Comment: Wow! Thanks. Seems I am on right track. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

I have used alternate method in which I am using SQL INSERT to insert new records and SQL UPDATE to update existing records.

Answer (score 0):

## Steps to follow

1. Remove the parentheses: If you will run this query it's
   working. But the syntax error will be displaying. For example:

   ```
   INSERT INTO stationlist (Comd,Stn,Pin,Location)
       VALUES ('aaa','bb',11,'ddd') ON DUPLICATE KEY

   UPDATE Comd = 'abcd'
       ,Stn = 'AFSB'
       ,Pin = 999
       ,Location = 'Delhi'
   ```
2. For me my query is as below:

   ```
   INSERT INTO dragdrop (id,TEXT,listorder)
       VALUES (7,'HTML',6) ON DUPLICATE KEY

   UPDATE TEXT = 'JSON' ,listorder = 7
   ```
3. For reference to syntax highlighting error will be tracked on this [phpmyadmin issue](http://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/11628).